# Help needed to install MT760e WiFi driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, system-installation

Background
- Computer ASUS TP500LN
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Clean Install from bootable USB Drive (created from Ubuntu's Instructions) 
- Have downloaded MT760e-release driver
- Do not have internet access from this computer
- An ethernet cable does not allow access to the internet
- During the Install process I can access the internet using the ethernet cable.

Problem
I follow the instruction to install the driver, but received this error
LINE 10 : `make` not recongised.

Question

1. How can I install `make` so I can then install the driver?
2. Is there a method to install the driver without `make`?
3. Is there a method to install the driver during installation?
4. Is there a method to tell Ubuntu that the USB can be used as software source (replacing the CD/DVD option)

General Odd Questions

1. Why can the installer connect to the internet and not the OS using a wired connection?
2. Why is Ubuntu still using CD/DVD as the only option for software source (aside from the net)

Comment: To use the `make` command you need to have the `build-essential` package installed. `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: Update 3/08: Now Internet via Ethernet cable

Comment: @Edmund L : Thank you for the lead, I do have the problem that I cannot use apt-get because I have no internet (prior my update). I have since tried that and the install of the driver freezes.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting the Ethernet Cable allowed connection to the Internet.
(Thanks to Edmund L for the first command)

From there the commands are:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get git linux-headers-generic libelf-dev dkms
git clone https://github.com/benjarobin/MT7630E.git
cd ~/Downloads/MT7630E
sudo chmod +x ./install
sudo ./install
sudo dkms
```

Comment: Did you get the WiFi card to work?